# fancybox show scroll in main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

My fancybox popup sometimes is way too big and I want to show scrollbars on the main page (not inside fancybox). Could anybody please let me know how do I do this?

Please see the attached screenshot. It shows no scrollbars at all. How do I fix this using fancybox 2?

[image]

Comment: show what js code (fancybox custom script) you are using

Answer (score 1):

You must use `fitToView` with `false` parameter. Hope this helps.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs